# How to lighten up colors of syntax highlighting?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I need to make syntax colors lighter (for dark themes). Globaly or not.

Comment: The original poster will need to attack each color of each theme on a one by one basis and change each color to suit personal preferences.  There is no built-in dimmer switch that affects a broad range of faces.  The down-vote and/or vote-to-close was probably because this is not a straight programming question with sample code demonstrating a valiant effort on the part of the original poster -- i.e., what has already been tried by the original poster, and how that results differs from the ultimate goal.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for posting a solution that uses the `face-list` and increments setting the new values with `set-face-background` and `set-face-foreground`.  It is always nice to learn new tricks.  While it is not technically a built-in solution, your libraries are indeed reliable *fixtures* in the Emacs community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact there **is** a *dimmer switch* that affects all faces.  There are in fact several such dimmer switches: (1) to dim/brighten, (2) to heighten colors or make them more washed-out, (3) to move toward or away from a particular hue, or (4, 5, 6) to make them all more - or less - red, blue, or green.

All of these dimmer switches that act on all faces together are rolled into a single command -- well two commands: one for the face backgrounds (**`doremi-all-faces-bg+`**) and one for the face foregrounds (**`doremi-all-faces-fg+`**).

These are two of several [**Do Re Mi**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) color incrementer commands.  The others work on individual faces or on frame backgrounds and foregrounds.  All of these commands work the same way. After invoking the command (e.g. `M-x doremi-all-faces-bg+`):

```
You are prompted for the color COMPONENT to increment/decrement (a character):

  `r` - red
  `g` - green
  `b` - blue
  `h` - hue (basic color)
  `s` - saturation (purity)
  `v` - value (brightness)

  `R` - red, green, and blue, at the same time
  `H` - hue, saturation, and value, at the same time

`R` and `H` increment all components of the respective color spaces,
according to the value of INCREMENT.

You can at any time change, to increment/decrement a different color
component (r, g, b, h, s, v, R, or H).  For example, you can type `r`
and use the arrow keys or mouse wheel to change the red component,
then type `b` and use the arrows or wheel to change the blue
component, and so on, all in the same call.
```

For desaturating, that is, to render all colors more pale or washed-out, you just use `s`.

See [Angry Fruit Salad](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngryFruitSalad#WashOutIn) for more information about this synchronized saturation dimming of all faces.

You can use the dimmer switch whenever you want, if you want more or less washed out colors. Or you can use it to find a good combination and then save the current face values in your `custom-file` (or your init file, if you do not have a `custom-file`, which you should have).

More likely, you will want to experiment by "dimming" and then follow that up with some customization of a few individual faces. For that, you can use the similar dimmer switches for individual faces (`doremi-face-bg+` etc.).  Incrementing qualities of all faces at once is a bit rough-and-ready. But for something like desaturating, it is very quick and does the job well.

Note that the face changes made using **Do Re Mi** commands are not saved automatically.  User option **`doremi-customization-status`** controls how Customize views such changes.

- By default, Customize sees them as if you had made them using the Customize UI.  In this case, you can use command `customize-unsaved` to open Customize for them all, where you can save individual changes or all of the together.
- If you set option `doremi-customization-status` to value `outside` then Customize sees the changes instead as having been made outside Customize.  In this case, you can use command `customize-rogue` to open Customize for them all.
- If you set the option to anything else then Customize ignores the changes altogether - you cannot use Customize to save them until you reapply them using Customize itself or a command such as `set-face-foreground`.  This option setting can be useful if you just want to experiment and do not want Customize to see what you do.